# How to remove blur around mirror seam?

Tags: mesh, mirror

I'm trying to mirror my object, but blur shows up around the seam, and it's only on one side of the object. How exactly can I prevent this from happening as it looks pretty bad when applying material. Here's the

[image]

Note: It's only when I shade the object smooth it appears. (Not sure if that's obvious, just wanted to mention it)

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add a wireframe picture or model file

Comment: It looks as if smooth shading has been set for the circled faces, but not the others? (You can set smooth shading per face)

Comment: @mma78 I've added a picture of the wireframe

Comment: @RobinBetts I select the whole model when applying smooth shading. Wouldn't this prevent what you're describing?

Comment: @Plekz Sure, if that was your last move.. edge properties can also influence.. do you have sharpness/bevel weight/ custom normals? Probably best to share a representative chunk of your file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @RobinBetts Sorry about that. Files uploaded now

Comment: Hi, Plekz, Nothing to apologise for.... fixing is simple, finding the root cause not so easy. Answering in a while

Comment: thanks @Plekz . i thinks you should mark sharp edges not seam

Answer (score 1):

The Fix: If you don't need the non-uniform object-level scale for animation, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply the scale of your object.

*Why* that's a fix isn't obvious .. your object is scaled equally in X and Y, (though not  in Z). I would have thought normals would be transformed consistently.. it's strange that normals of adjacent faces which previously were equal, are not equal after after this scaling transform. I think we would have to dig into that calculation to figure it out.

The object has an *Edge Split* modifier with a threshold angle. You can sharpen the object all round by increasing the smoothing threshold in there. (The non-uniform scale makes the face-angles vary around the circumference, even though they all measure the same in object-space, so the effect progresses around the circle, rather than happening all at once)

*Edge Split* prevents normal interpolation across edges by duplicating them .. it's almost a legacy feature in this context. Probably better to use Auto Smooth, which splits the vertex-per-face normals, rather than the faces themselves. (You can increase the smoothing threshold angle in there, too, for *a* fix, but the *right* fix is to apply the scale, unless you need it the way it is.)

Comment: Holy crap, thank you very much! I'm not completely confident in my blender skills so this help has been amazing!